# What are the hotkeys to move units?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-hd

How can I move people in AEO2 II HD with hotkeys? I know how to do this with the right click of the mouse, but I want to move them with the keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a way to move 100% with the keyboard.
The closest is 'M' (for move), then left-click.

Answer (score 0):

Open up the unit screen (select it) and hover over the buttons in the left bottom. You will see some actions that can be performed (eg, move, guard, patrol). Hover over the move button, read the text and you will see what the hotkey is :)